# Act on every nth file given in an argument to a script

Tags: macos, bash, for-loop

I have a bash script that I want to launch, using some files as arguments. I need then to add every *nth* file of that list, to an array.

It thought about using a `for` loop, but it seems it can only do one of those two thing at once. Of course, I'd like the resulting code to be as simple and small as possible, but the only pre-requisites are that it must be done in bash, and only with tools that come with the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indirect variable references to reference arguments numerically:

```
selectedargs=()
n=4
for ((i=1; i<$#; i+=n)); do
    selectedargs+=("${!i}")
done
```

Comment: Chosen as the new best answer, since the for loop looks cleaner and more easily maintainable. I have, however, one question. It works, and I can understand most of it, except what does the `!` do exactly, in this situation?

Comment: @user137369: The `!` tells bash to perform [indirect expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection) -- essentially, it replaces the variable name with its value, then treats that as *another* variable name and replaces *that* with its value. So, for example, with i=12 it'll turn `"${!i}"` into `"${12}"`, and then that into the 12th argument to the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `for` loop is pretty appropriate. Here, for `n=9`, I create an array containing the digits 0 to 99, and then use a for loop to create an array containing every 9th digit of the original array:

```
x=( {0..99} )
y=()
n=9
for ((i=0; i<${#x[@]}; i=i+n)); do
    y+=( "${x[i]}" )
done
```

Comment: But you're creating an array before the loop and acting on that one. What I want to is to add to what starts as an empty array, and I have no idea how many fields it will have. I need to run `my_script file1 file2 file2` and have it act on them (possibly with `$@`) acting then on every *nth* of it.

Comment: @user137369 What's stopping you? You could substitute `"$@"` for `"${x[@]}"` in my loop and it would still act on every `nth` of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file names are arguments, you can use `shift` to discard arguments you don't want:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()
n=8
while (( $# > 0 )); done
   files+=( $1 )
   shift $n || shift $#
done
```

The extra `shift` is necessary because `shift` does nothing if its argument is greater than the number of remaining arguments.